# Big difference in build time between win32 and x64 using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build

I use [Visual Studio 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2010) to build my C++ project. There are three machine-generated-files, each with 30,000-40,000 lines of code and some smaller ones from myself.

In Win32 the build will take less than 60 seconds.

In x64, the build will take up to 20-30 minutes at the outputline:

> 1>  Generating Code...

I'm not sure if that has something to do with each other, but if I want to build the project (win32 and x64), I have to enable the option \bigobj

Otherwise I get this output:

> fatal error C1128: number of sections exceeded object file format limit : compile with /bigobj

I had no problems so far with projects without big files and I used the same setting in the project properties.

What could the problem be?

Is this a well-known problem with x64? Are there some project properties that will speed up the build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 is really "quirky" in 64 bit builds. I've had some issues with it, particularly in the linking stage (very very slow). There are some reports about it: *[Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate really slow compile time](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ccb8d9e8-a870-4cd1-ae85-98f767dcf9bd/visual-studio-2010-ultimate-really-slow-compile-time?forum=vssetup)*

My suggestion is to try [Visual Studio 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2013). It's compatible with Visual Studio 2010 projects and it solved all my building issues, so it does see that Visual Studio 2010 has some unresolved bugs.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try with VS2013